# How to loop through data from php in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, repeat, region

I want to ask how to the repeat a region in javascript?
The data are dynamic and I want to find all items through php `do...while` loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
    <?php do{ ?>
        var chart<?php echo $row_RecAllAnswers['q_id']; ?> = new CanvasJS.Chart("<?php echo $row_RecAllAnswers['q_id']; ?>", {
            theme: "theme2",//theme1
            title:{
                text: "No. " + "<?php echo $row_RecAllAnswers['q_id']; ?>"              
            },
            animationEnabled: true,   // change to true
            data: [              
            {
                // Change type to "bar", "splineArea", "area", "spline", "pie",etc.
                type: "column",
                dataPoints: [
                    { label: "A" ,  y: <?php echo $row_RecAllAnswers['A']; ?>  },
                    { label: "B", y: <?php echo $row_RecAllAnswers['B']; ?>  },
                    { label: "C", y: <?php echo $row_RecAllAnswers['C']; ?>  },
                    { label: "D",  y: <?php echo $row_RecAllAnswers['D']; ?>  }
                ]
            }
            ]
        });
        chart<?php echo $row_RecAllAnswers['q_id']; ?>.render();
        chart<?php echo $row_RecAllAnswers['q_id']; ?> = {};
        window.alert(<?php echo $row_RecAllAnswers['q_id']; ?>);
        <?php } while ($row_RecAllAnswers = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecAllAnswers));  ?> 
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You really should not use PHP to output JavaScript code.

Comment: @JayBlanchard
But how to repeat the javascript area according how many rows in database? Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do with your JavaScript, but you could write JavaScript that loops through your DOM elements. In addition, please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [json_encode](https://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) to convert your mysql query result to JSON.
2. Write the JSON to your HTML.
3. In Javascript use a foreach on the JSON array to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

json encode that php array into a javascript variable and then loop through that variable. In twig I do it like this:

```
var objectName = {{ phpVariable|json_encode|raw }};
```

so I think this should work find in PHP (did not test it):

```
var objectName = <?php echo json_encode($phpVariable); ?>;
```

Then the javascript variable 'objectName' will contain your data and now you can use regular javascript to loop through the data. You can also use underscore as it is easier.

```
_.each(objectName, function(item, key){
//do stuff here
});
```